# jQuery can not get correct drop down menu values from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601415/2118559

However I can not get it to work correctly

At first in outside php file have such array `$fetch_child_topic`

```
Array
(
   [TopicName] => A
   [TopicUrl] => a
)
```

In the outside PHP file I convert it to JSON

```
echo json_encode($fetch_child_topic, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

In the 'main file' the JavaScript looks like this `{"TopicName":"A","TopicUrl":"a"}` its name is `data`.

And here trying to create drop down menu

```
 for (var text in data) {
    alert( 'text ' + text + ' data' + data );
    var val = data[text];
    $('<option/>').val(val).text(text).appendTo($('#first_subcat_id'))
 };
```

Drop down menu get long list with numbers like 0,1,2... but I would expect to see the letter `A`.

In the alert I see

```
text 0 data{"TopicName":"A","TopicUrl":"a"}
text 1 data{"TopicName":"A","TopicUrl":"a"}
....
text 31 data{"TopicName":"A","TopicUrl":"a"}
```

Something is wrong... but I can't understand what.

Any ideas, please?

EDIT

code in php file is like this (code a bit modified, to have only one column)

Get data from mysql

```
try {
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT TopicName FROM $table_name WHERE UpperTopicName = ?"); 
$stmt->execute( array($_POST['main_topic']) );
$fetch_child_topic = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}//try {
catch (PDOException $e){
echo "<br> Url DataBase Error: " .htmlspecialchars( $e->getMessage() , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'<br>';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "  Url General Error: ".htmlspecialchars( $e->getMessage() ).'<br>';
}
```

and

```
echo json_encode($fetch_child_topic, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

**Solution**

after get data from external php file (name of jquery var is `data`), did this

```
var data = $.parseJSON( data );
$.map( data, function( val, i ) {
$('<option/>').val(i).html(val).appendTo('#first_subcat_id');
});
```

In drop down menu get letters A, B (as expected)

Comment: I think you are confusing jQuery (a JavaScript library) with JavaScript object literals (a way of creating JavaScript objects).

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript should end up looking like this in the source.

```
var data = {"TopicName":"A","TopicUrl":"a"};  // <== this is a javascript object literal assigned to the variable "data"

var text, val;
for (text in data) {
    val = data[text];
    alert( 'text ' + text + ', val' + val);
    $('<option/>').val(val).text(text).appendTo($('#first_subcat_id'));
}
```

if you have some HTML like

```
<select id="first_subcat_id"></select>
```

If your `var data =` line isn't structured like that, then you have an issue somewhere in your PHP.

If your PHP file was generating the entire document you could just embed the output from the `json_encode` into the JavaScript something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?= json_encode($fetch_child_topic, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>;

var text, val;
for (text in data) {
    val = data[text];
    alert( 'text ' + text + ', val' + val);
    $('<option/>').val(val).text(text).appendTo($('#first_subcat_id'));
}
</script>
```

I don't think fetchAll would return an Array in the format you've shown at the top of your example. It returns an Array of associative arrays so probably something more like

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
      (
         [TopicName] => A
         [TopicUrl] => a
      )
)
```

You need to get rid of the outer array. So just do something like this... depending on what your actual output from the SQL query returns.

```
$fetch_child_topic = $fetch_child_topic[0];
```

Comment: Yes, If I name var data (not related to php) then drop down menu see TopicName and TopicUrl. Something incorrect with php

Comment: @user2118559 where do you output the echo statement, can you show the surrounding text?

Comment: Do you mean code in 'outside' php file? If yes, I will add the code in the question

Comment: @user2118559 Yes, please. I'm wondering how you are getting the string generated by the `json_encode()` function to your JavaScript.

Comment: Appears, that `json_encode` passes string and not array. Tried to change to jquery array. Added `var data = $.parseJSON( data );` and now in drop down menu see correct number of numbers. But expected to see letters.

Comment: @user2118559 Yes, it does, but that's not your main issue. The structure of your array is wrong for the JavaScript you want to generate. See my updated answer

Comment: Finally got solution! will post